# onReceivedError not working in android Marshmallow and below

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to display a custom error page using `onReceivedError` but it is not showing error. HTML it shows on default webpage not available error only

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                super.onPageFinished(view,url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

error.html file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body style="text-align:center;font-size:16px;">
<img src="05.png" width="100%">
<div>
    <p>Please Check your internet Connection</p>
    <p>Please Check Wifi</p>
    <p>There is no response from server</p>
</div>
<button style="background-color:#3700B3;color:#fff;border:0;border-radius:5px;padding:7px 15px;" onclick="Reload();">Try Again</button>
<script>
    function Reload(){
     location.reload();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this, please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified the file path? Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: yeah i have verified file path and is correct.

Comment: Hi.
Is it possible to send me the full code?
Or ask and complete?

Comment: @JavadDehban which file do you need?

Comment: class main and file HTML.

Comment: @JavadDehban can we connect on anydesk?

Comment: Can I send the project to my email?
javaddehban1@gmail.com

Comment: @JavadDehban can you please check your email

Answer (score 2):

This question has been around for quite a long time, and probably you already got the answer. But as a newbie enthusiast, I will try to answer your question to help other newbie who might face same problem as yours.

Your code actually is fine already. There is only one tiny problem. Always call onReceivedError only after onPageFinished. Don't ever call onReceivedError before onPageFinished.

You might also want to call onReceivedHttpError to make sure all errors are handled by your html asset.

So your code should be as below.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                super.onPageFinished(view,url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, 
                                        WebResourceError error){
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request,
                                            WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
                super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
            }
});
```